# ng-click doesn't work when the button is floated to the right

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Ok this is such a strange one.

I am working in an Angular Project, I have a button with a ng-click attached. It doesn't fire. If I remove the css that floats the button to the right, then it works fine.

HTML:

```
<button id="btn" ng-click="myFunction()">Name</button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    float: right;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Javascript / Angular Controller:

```
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {

 $scope.myFunction = function() {
  console.log('Hello World');
 };

});
```

Simply changing the CSS to:

```
button {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Makes it work again

Comment: Maybe it's related to an other part of the code that could be above that button ?

Comment: I stripped out everything else @VincentG it is 100% related to the floating of the button. As soon as I remove that CSS class it's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think when you float it to the right, some other html is on top of your button and it's preventing you from making the click.

> Add a **z-index: 9999** to your button's css

Hope it helped :)